# Excluding a "spook" pages from <marquee> line made from Jekyll list of page

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I am using the following expression

```
<ul>

{% assign mypages = site.pages | sort: "order" %}
{% for page in mypages %}

<li class="intro">
<a href="{{ page.url | absolute_url }}">{{ 
page.title }}</a>
</li>
{% endfor %}
 </ul>
```

at my [site's](https://indexmod.gq/) index.md to generate list of all pages and all works perfect

Also I am using modified version of the above-mentioned code

```
<marquee behavior="scroll" scrollamount="17" 
direction="left" height="80px" loop="-1" 
style="border:0px" width="99%" padding="0px" 
onmouseover="this.stop();" 
onmouseout="this.start();">

{% assign mypages = site.pages | sort: "order" %} 
{% for page in mypages %}

<a href="{{page.url|absolute_url}}"> {{ 
page.shortname }} <span class="rate">{% include 
indexmod.html %}</a></span> <span class="rex"> | 
</span> {% endfor %}
</marquee>
```

to generate Bloomberg-like scroll marquee area made from some meta data and rating value (include indexmod.html), but there are appearing 7 "spook" pages without title and linking to: 404.html, feed.xml, sitemap.xml, robots.txt, redirects.json, style.css...

I have try to add thouse pages into ignore list in _config.yml

[image: Fragmet of _config.yml]

Thanks in advance for trick how to add all of them into some exclude filter.

Here is screen of the mentioned marquee on my site. Topic 032C 0.24 is linking to a real article with title "032C" with rate 0.24, next topic is wrong and linking to 404.html with rating 0.0, next topic is good again 4S4R, and all rest zeros are titles empty rates for technical files of my site. I have left only 2 real articles on my site for easier fixing the glitch.

[image: Screen of mentioned marquee area]

Answer (score 0):

I see there is no any comments. I have fixed part of problem using exclude line in front matter for 404.md. But still have question about other 5 files with extensions .css .json .xml .txt.

Therefore  I am redirecting rest of question to [a new topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51819762/exclude-css-json-xml-text-from-site-pages-in-jekyll)