# How to stop style.css to be considered as the Jekyll Page?

Tags: css, ruby, jekyll, liquid, github-pages

I am using expression

```
{% assign mypages = site.pages | sort: "order" %} {% for page in 
mypages %}
{% unless page.exclude %}

<a href="{{page.url|absolute_url}}"> {{ page.shortname }} <span 
class="rate">{% include indexmod.html %}</a></span> <span class="rex"> 
| </span>
{% endunless %}
{% endfor %}
```

for layout, and see unwanted style.css considered as a Jekyll Page

I have try different tricks from [GitHub discussion "/css/main.css considered as a Jekyll:Page? #3151"](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/3151), but it does not help. Sometimes I cutting away all styles.

Please, clear how to let the styles to work properly, but exclude it from generating as link to a Jekyll Page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excluding a "spook" pages from <marquee> line made from Jekyll list of page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51776730/excluding-a-spook-pages-from-marquee-line-made-from-jekyll-list-of-page)

Comment: Try moving your `css/` folder with style.css into the `public/` folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `site.html_pages` instead of `site.pages`, as it will exclude all pages that don't output with the `.html` extension (i.e. `style.css`). You'll find both listed here:

https://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/#site-variables